Why should we use time independent states to derive the ideal gas law?
I've been reading the 2nd edition of Thermal Physics by Kittel and Kroemer, and I'm puzzled by how they derive the ideal gas law in Chapter 3, in particular the choice of quantum mechanical basis.
On pages 72-73, they compute the partition function of one atom by assuming that it's in a cubical box and then computing the orbitals of the free particle wave equation (eq 58), presumably by separation of variables (between the time and space variables).
Assuming time independence makes sense to me if we're dealing with an atom or molecule that's just sitting there doing nothing (the ground state), but these gas particles are bouncing around in a box.
Picking the time independent basis is certainly convenient for doing the calculation, but what justification can be advanced for picking this basis and not some other?

"Why should we use time independent states... an atom or molecule that's just sitting there doing nothing (the ground state), but..." All eigenstates of the hamiltonian have the same trivial time dependence $e^{-iE_n t}$, not just the ground state... So, why would you single out the ground state?

@hft OK, any of the eigenstates of the hamiltonian.  I picked the ground state because it's obvious one.  All of them correspond to stable (in the absense of an external EM field) systems that aren't in motion, and I'm thinking of atoms here, not molecules (no vibrational or rotational modes).  But the atoms in an ideal gas are in motion, so why use this basis?

What edition of the text are you looking at? What specific equations are you concerned about? Why don't you write those in your post so that anyone else other than you might have the slightest idea what you are complaining about.

@hft, I'll edit the post to reflect your comments, but I'm not complaining about anything.  I'm asking if anybody can provide a justification for picking this particular basis.

The basis being chosen is the basis of eigenstates of the Hamiltonian operator. One reason this basis is useful in statistical mechanics because often a crucial question in statistical mechanics is to determine the probability distribution of energies in a system (eg, the "canonical ensemble"), and each eigenstate of the Hamiltonian has a definite energy. Additionally, a time-independent basis is a useful thing to have, in general, for more or less the same reason it is useful in classical mechanics, when finding a basis for ordinary 3-dimensional vectors: it's usually mathematically simpler to not have to track the time dependence of a reference frame in addition to time dependence in the system itself.
Generally speaking, if the Hamiltonian is time-independent, then the eigenstates of the Hamiltonian will have trivial time dependence. So there's nothing really magical or surprising about the fact that we have time-independent basis states to work with for a gas of non-relativistic particles.
It seems to me that part of your objection here is an appeal to classical reasoning that particles in a gas should be "moving." However, keep in mind that energy eigenstates are often not very "classical" states. For a free particle, the energy eigenstates are plane waves, and are also eigenstates of the momentum operator. These states are completely delocalized, in fact having infinite position uncertainty. So they are very unlike your idea of a classical particle as a dot in space. To get something more classical, you can form wavepackets by superposing energy eigenstates, but these wavepackets won't have definite energy and will be more difficult to work with in a statistical mechanics application. So, the convenient states to work with in this case don't behave particularly classically, and so it's not a good idea to rely on your classical intuition for how they should behave.
Now, at least morally speaking, it should be true that for an ideal gas at, say, room temperature, the "uncertainty in energy" you get by creating wavepackets (superpositions of energy eigenstates which are localized in space and "move around") is not very important, even though the calculation is easier with energy eigenstates. After all, you can also derive the ideal gas law by thinking about classical particles bouncing around. However, the ultimate goal of this quantum analysis is to apply it to more extreme situations: identical quantum particles (bosons and fermions), the thermal distribution of photons which resolves the ultraviolet catastrophe, the distribution of massive bosons at low temperatures which is relevant for Bose-Einstein condensates, the distribution of fermions near the Fermi temperature which is relevant for understanding phenomena as diverse as conductivity and neutron stars. In these scenarios, it is essential to use quantum mechanics, and important to use quantum thinking instead of falling back on classical concepts that can be misleading.

Thank you.  Good answer, and it's kind of the one I already suspected - these are the "convenient states to work with".  My objection here is more along the lines of asking if we have a better reason to pick this basis.  Do you know if there's any kind of theorem that says it doesn't matter which basis we choose?

@BrentBaccala Eh I'm not quite sure I said they are "convenient states to work with." It's more like, by definition, what you're interested in computing for the canonical ensemble is the probability distribution of measuring the system to have a given energy. Since the energy eigenstates are the eigenstates with definite energy, this is saying you want to express the canonical ensemble as a probability distribution over energy eigenstates. One way to express this more formally is in terms of the density matrix. For the canonical ensemble, the density matrix takes the form (...)

(...) $\rho=\frac{e^{-\beta H}}{{\rm tr}[e^{- \beta H}]}$, where $\beta=kT$ and $H$ is the Hamiltonian operator, and the denominator involves a trace. Then the probability for a given microstate with energy $|E\rangle$ is $\langle E | \rho | E \rangle$. (If you want the probability to observe energy $E$ you also need to include a factor for the density of states). You could insert a complete set of states in some other basis between $|E\rangle$ and $\rho$, which is essentially what you want to do, but it will just make the calculation more difficult.
